# Can you forecast with multiple trajectories?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I am new to time-series machine learning and have a, perhaps, trivial question.

I would like like to forecast the temperature for a particular region. I could train a model using the hourly data points from the first 6 days of the week and then evaluate its performance on the final day. Therefore the training set would have 144 data points (6*24) and the test set would have 24 data points (24*1). Likewise, I can train a new model for regions B-Z and evaluate each of their individual performances. My question is, can you train a SINGLE model for the predictions across multiple different regions? So the region label should be an input of course since that will effect the temperature evolution.

Can you train a single model that forecasts for multiple trajectories rather than just one? Also, what might be a good metric for evaluating its performance? I was going to use mean absolute error but maybe a correlation is better?

Comment: You can you deep learning to do this. But you cant train in the 6 first days of the week and evalatue on the final day, since you will need a label in train to your model predict. For each day in train, you need the value and the label that means what you want your model outputs for you.

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is usually called panel (or supervised) forecasting. There is no need to do deep learning, but of course you can try. Any other standard machine learning algorithm (random forest, etc.) or statistical forecasting algorithm (ARIMA, etc) can also be adapted to solve this kind of problem. There are few libraries that solve this problem off-the-shelf. One is pysf with a tutorial on weather data (https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/pysf/blob/master/examples/Walkthrough.ipynb), another one is gluon-ts (mostly deep-learning methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can train with multiple series of data from different region the question that you ask is an ultimate goal of deep learning by create a 1 model to do every things, predict every region correctly and so on. However, if you want to generalize your model that much you normally need a really huge model, I'm talking about 100M++ parameter and to train that data you also need tons of Data maybe couple TB or PB, so you also need a super powerful computer to train that thing something like GOOGLE data center. Coming to your next question, the metric, you may use just simple RMS error or mean absolute error will work fine.

Here is what you need to focus **Training Data**, there is no super model that take garbage and turn it in to gold, same thing here garbage in garbage out. You need a pretty good datasets that can represent whole environment of what u are trying to solve. For example, you want to create model to predict that if you hammer a glass will it break, so you have maybe 10 data for each type of glass and all of them break when u hammer it. so, you train the model and it just predict break every single time, then you try to predict with a bulletproof glass and it does not break, so your model is wrong. Therefore, you need a whole data of different type of glass then your model maybe predict it correctly. Then compare this to your 144 data points, I'm pretty sure it won't work for your case.

Therefore, I would say yes you can build that 1 model fits all but there is a huge price to pay.

Comment: This exactly answered my question - thank you! I agree the quality and the quantity of the data are a huge concern. However, I would still like to try. Do you have any good python library recommendations for this type of multiple trajectory forecasting problem as well? Thanks again

Comment: you can use PyTorch or Keras. I suggest you practice Keras and go deeper to tensorflow low level API, it can help you build more complex model later on and support TPU for training.